# Change in duration of Windows Task Scheduler running task

Tags: windows, task, scheduler, duration

Is there a need to restart a task on Windows task scheduler if I increase the duration for which it has to run? For instance I started a task on 27th June to run everyday from 7am for next 10 hours at every 10 minute interval. On 28th I updated the task to run from 7am for next 15 hours. Do I need to restart the task or the running task picks up the new time and continues to run for 15 hours?

Comment: Hi Zbnj, welcome to Stackoverflow. This community is rather focused on development issues, than machine administration. You'll find other communities in the StackExchange group (or else) where members are more willing / ready to help on the topic you raise in this issue. Sincerly hoping you'll find anwsers to your questions

Comment: Oops sorry for that. This is the first ever time I posted a question. Will try to find the admin community. Thanks for the response. Meanwhile any pointers to reach the admin community would help.Thanks again.

Comment: you'll probably be interested in [superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [serverfault/windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows).

Comment: Mind you, if you have any question about scripting, even for very profound administrative issues, Stackoverflow may very well be your place!